# Why was Sakurai Takahiro recast in Psycho-Pass 2?

Tags: psycho-pass

In Psycho-Pass (season 1), Sakurai Takahiro voiced Makishima Shougo. In Psycho-Pass 2, he voices Hinakawa Shou. I find it strange that the same voice actor would be cast to voice two different important characters in the same show.

Sure, it's common for a voice actor to voice multiple side characters, I guess to reduce the total number of voice actors that need to be hired (e.g. from this season, Fukuyama Jun voices Hunchoceratops and a few side characters in Amagi Brilliant Park; and Kayano Ai voices a number of side characters in Shirobako). But two different main characters? That's weird.

Weirder still, Sakurai is severely playing against type as Hinakawa - soft-spoken roles just aren't what he does, for the most part. Do we know why Sakurai was recast as a different character in Psycho-Pass 2?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this has been confirmed, but it's most likely that Takahiro Sakurai enjoyed playing Makishima Shogo in Psycho Pass. With all the praise he got, I think he enjoyed the project (Psycho Pass) so much that he wanted to get back in the action even if it was a role he wouldn't normally take on.

Comment: Is there anything to back up what you are claiming here?